# Auto-renewable Subscriptions Level upgrade

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, itunes-store, auto-renewable

I have set up some Auto renewable subscription with 
- 1 month at $10 and 
- 2 months at $15.

I would like to change it to have 2 months at $5. Should the user upgrade their subscription from 1 month to 2 months, will it still apply even though the cost $5 will be lower than the 1 month at $10.

Refering to the Upgrade description from here: https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev7f2d6b652

Will the user still get refunded pro-rata and immediately charged the new lower price?

Answer (score 0):

From my tests, the above scenarios does not constitute an upgrade since it is at a cheaper price.